# $M \neq 0$ but $M^* = 0$.

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Let $A$ be a ring. For any left, resp. right $A$-module $M$ give the abelian group $\text{Hom}_A(M, A)$ the structure of a ring $A$-module (to be denoted $M^*$), resp. left $A$-module (to be denoted $^*M$). What is an example where $M \neq 0$ but $M^* = 0$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $A = \mathbb Z$ and $M = \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

Easy: let $A$ be an integral domain (hence it is commutative), and $I$ a non-zero ideal. Then
$$\operatorname{Hom}(A/I,A)=\operatorname{Ann}_A(I)=0.$$